Prove isomorphism (M $ ⊗_ {R} $N)$/I($M $⊗_{R}$N)$ \cong (M/IM) $⊗$_{R/I}$ (N/IN)
Let R be a commutative ring, I an ideal of $R$ and $M$ and N R-modules. Prove isomorphism
$(M $$ ⊗_
{R}$$ N)$$/I($M $⊗_{R}$N)$ \cong (M/IM) $⊗$_{R/I}$ $(N/IN)$.
I tried to use the Milnor square but I do not have any idea how to use it in this context.

Your problem statement here does not contain the word "natural"

Please use MathJax to (re)format the mathematics in your question. Here's how.

See Theorem 2.19 here for a more general result and Example 2.21 covers nearly what you ask about (just note the target module in Example 2.21 is a tensor product over $R$ rather than $R/I$).
To get an $R/I$-module tensor product on the right side, use Theorem 4.5 (with your $M \otimes_R N$ in place of $M$) and Corollary 6.26  (with your $R/I$ and $N$ in place of $S$ and $M'$ there) here, where $S$ is the target of a ring homomorphism $R \to S$ to do a base extension from $R$-modules to $S$-modules.

Thank you very much for your help. I think that the second link  you posted is the same as the first but I’m not sure.

I have corrected the second link, which was meant to send you somewhere else.
