How to show that ${_R}M \otimes_R {_R}N \cong {_R}(M \otimes_{R/I} N)$ for $R/I$-modules $N$ and $M$
Let $R$ and $S$ be commutative rings, $\psi: R \to S$ be a surjective ring homomorphism and $M, N$ be $S$-modules. There is a natural map of $R$-modules $\varphi: {_R}M \otimes_R {_R}N \to {_R}(M \otimes_S N)$. I want to show that $\varphi$ is an isomorphism. It is clear to me why this is surjective, but how do I show injectivity?
I tried to do this by showing that ${_R}(M \otimes_S N)$ fulfills the universal property of ${_R}M \otimes_R {_R}N$, but that hasn't got me anywhere. I take some $R$-module $P$ and an $R$-bilinear map ${_R}M \times {_R}N \to P$ and have to show that this factors uniquely through ${_R}(M \otimes_S N)$. But for this, I need to construct a map out of ${_R}(M \otimes_S N)$, so I need to use the universal property of $M \otimes_S N$. But for that I need to have some $S$-module to which I have a bilinear map, which I don't know how to obtain. I of course can just take $\newcommand\quotient[2]{{^{\Large #1}}/{_{ \Large #2}}} \quotient{P}{IP}$ (with $S \cong \quotient{R}{I}$, which we have because $\psi$ is surjective), but then I just get an $S$-linear map $M \otimes_S N \to \quotient{P}{IP}$ when I need to really end up with an $R$-linear map ${_R}(M \otimes_S N) \to P$, and I don't know how to obtain the latter from the former.

This is a duplicate question. But to give you a hint already: Don't show injectivity. Construct an inverse map. Recall that an isomorphism is an invertible homomorphism. This is the best, useful, scalable and easy definition of an isomorphism. Forget about injective and surjective, this is a lemma, not a definition.

@MartinBrandenburg I've also tried doing that, but I hit the same obstacle: To construct a map ${_R}(M \otimes_S N) \to {_R}M \otimes_R {_R}N$, I want to use the universal property of $M \otimes_S N$, but then I need an $S$-module, which ${_R}M \otimes_R {_R}N$ just isn't.

@MartinBrandenburg If you could point me to the question of which this is a duplicate, I would be very grateful. I have tried searching for terms like "tensor product over quotient ring" to no avail.

Do as you already wrote, and show $IP=0$

Hint: $S$-modules are the same as $R$-modules that are annihilated by $I$. In this respect, the tensor product over $R$ actually is (comes from) an $S$-module.

@Ben That's just not true. We can take $R = \mathbb{Z}$, $I = \langle 2 \rangle$ and $P = \mathbb{Z}$. Then $P$ is an $R$-module, but $IP \neq 0$.

@MartinBrandenburg I know this, but for some reason I can't see formally how this helps me.

@Smiley1000 of course $IP=0$ is not true for just any module, in your case $P=M\otimes N$ with $IM=IN=0$

@Ben I think I understand your suggestion now. I can consider ${_R}M \otimes_R {_R}N$ to be an $S$-module by choosing preimages for my scalar and then use this to construct an inverse to the obvious map.

@Ben Thanks again for the hint. I tried to write this up as an answer at the following link: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/5004652/491450 . I would appreciate it if you could tell me whether that was what you had in mind.

@MartinBrandenburg Thanks for the pointer to the other question. My question is exactly a duplicate of that one. However, my question is not a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4905167/prove-isomorphism-m-%e2%8a%97-r-n-im-%e2%8a%97-rn-cong-m-im-%e2%8a%97-r-i-n-in . The isomorphism asked there is $$\newcommand\quotient[2]{{^{\Large #1}}/{_{ \Large #2}}} (M \otimes_R N) \otimes_R \quotient{R}{I} \cong \left( M \otimes_R \quotient{R}{I} \right) \otimes_R \left( N \otimes_R \quotient{R}{I} \right)$$ for $R$-modules $N$ and $M$, which is not the same thing as what I asked.

It is equivalent when you think about it a bit (and fix your typo, the second tensor product is over the quotient). Use what we wrote here. We have the notion of so-called abstract duplicates. This is one example. They serve to link equivalent content.
